# How to add validation in reusable reactive form

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

This is reusable reactive form. How I can add `required` validation and error message for `street` formControlName in `app-child`?

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwvdro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

app.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input formControlName="name" />
    <app-child [address]="myForm"></app-child>
</form>
```

app.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [""],
      street: [""],
      zip: [""]
    });
  }
}
```

child.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="address">
      <label>Street: </label>
      <input formControlName="street" /><br />
      <label>Zip: </label>
      <input formControlName="zip" />
    </div>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() address: FormGroup;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs for validating user input: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#validating-form-input and https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: @Edric, in this case, how I can validate child `formControlName` (eg: street) ?

Comment: You can pass a validator to the relevant form controls in the `FormBuilder#group` method as documented in the first link I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your stackblitz to demonstrate my following answer: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhcbdw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

It's better practice to use ControlValueAccessor to create custom formcontrols.

check example from my [project](https://github.com/GreedyA1/dges/blob/develop/libs/forms/skills/src/lib/skill-form/skill-form.component.ts) of implementing custom formcontrol with validation.

you will need to add providers both for validation and for ControlValueAccessor.

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SkillFormComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SkillFormComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

basically you component should implement ControlValueAccessor. Where you will need to implement these functions:

```
  writeValue
  registerOnChange
  registerOnTouched
  setDisabledState
```

As for Validation you will need to implement only one function:

```
  validate
```

To get more info check out some examples on web.
this is pretty good [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8&t=1529s&ab_channel=AngularConnect).